# Django 2 Отображение имени и фотографии комментатора

Tags: python, django

Есть модель профиля пользователя и модель комментариев к статьям, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы имя комментатора и его изображение отображалось из модели пользователя в тексте комментария.

Я пытался решить эту проблему и получается так, что когда пользователь оставляет новый комментарий его текущее имя и текущая фотография отображаются в комментарии, но если изменить эти данные в настройках аккаунта, то в тексте комментария, данные остаются те же

Как реализовать такую систему, чтобы комментарий был привязан к пользователю и в нем отображалось имя и изображение, которое сохранено в профиле

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

views.py:

```
def post_detail(request,slug):
post = Post.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

if request.method == 'POST':
    # A comment was posted
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        # Assign the current post to the comment
        new_comment.author = request.user.first_name
        new_comment.post = post
        # Save the comment to the database
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'polls/post_detail.html', context={'post':post,
                                                          'comments': comments,
                                                          'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Comment: Вообще трудно представить, как они у вас остаются. Вы меняете изображение юзера, не перезагружая страницу с комментариями что ли?

Comment: @Александр как я понял, сохраняется не внешний ключ автора, а имя и фотография профиля

Answer (score 0):

Судя по этой строке:

```py
new_comment.author = request.user.first_name
```

в графе Автор комментария вы сохраняете имя автора, а не внешний ключ, отсылающий к его профилю (т.к. `user.first_name` - данные строкового типа, хранящие имя человека, который обратился с запросом). Смею полагать, что то же вы делаете и с изображением - сохраняете в БД локальную ссылку на изображение.

Чтобы сохранять данные о пользователе корректно, комментарий должен иметь два внешних ключа - один указывает на то, к какому посту относится комментарий, а второй - на автора комментария.

В таком случае при обновлении данных пользователя данные будут обновляться и у комментария, т.к. они привязаны не к конкретной подписи и картинке, а к профилю пользователя, откуда и будут брать имя и изображение профиля.

Comment: А как правильно передать ключ на автора комментария в моем случае?
user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE ) ?

Comment: @Daniil1703 в модели `Comment` я вообще не вижу у вас полей, которые были бы завязаны с автором. Вы точно скопировали класс полностью?

Comment: да, но там где я смотрел пример, не было никаких связей с автором. Чтобы соединить модель комментариев с пользователем, нужно добавить такое поле, в моем случае? user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)